# npm publish Failed PUT 402

Tags: npm

Working on a course that is having me go through a Bash tutorial.
I am stuck on the part where the code is asking me to publish my code so far. My instructions are as follows:

> ```
>  What good is a package manager without packages?  
>
>  Not very good.  
>
>  Luckily, that is not a problem for npm, because it's very easy for all  
>  npm users to publish their modules and share them with the world.  
>
>  Packages get into the registry by using the `npm publish` command.  
>
>  Try it now. There's not much to it.  
>
>  (Make sure you're still in the right project directory, though.  If you  
>  publish something by mistake, you can remove it, but there's no guarantee  
>  that no one saw it in the meantime.)  
>
>  Then run `how-to-npm verify` when you're done.
> ```

My code was:

```
jsf2008:~/workspace/dev (master) $ npm publish
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 402
npm ERR! code E402
npm ERR! You must sign up for private packages : @jsf2008/quit
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2017-08-22T14_44_29_746Z-debug.log
jsf2008:~/workspace/dev (master) $
```

I am quite lost here. I can't even find Error PUT 402 anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 161):

You're using [NPM Scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages). They are private by default which requires paying NPM for a private account. If your package is public, you can use the `--access=public` flag like this:

```
npm publish --access=public
```

Comment: $ npm publish --access=public
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 404
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Scope not found : @logcat-org/web-log
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@logcat-org/web-log' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/a/.npm/_logs/2017-09-17T04_05_55_360Z-debug.log

Comment: running this prints: `Failed PUT 400` & `"@yaireo/fakeScroll" is invalid for new packages : @yaireo/fakeScroll`

Comment: @vsync It probably does not like the capital letters.

Answer (score 19):

You can solve the problem by adding the following to your `package.json` file:

**package.json**

```json
"publishConfig": {
  "access": "public"
}
```

The [publishConfig value](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#publishconfig) manages the visibility of your package. If you define "public" access, then your package can be downloaded by everyone from the npm registry.

If you define "restricted" access, then consumers of your package have to add a `.npmrc` file to their own package in order to set an access token:

**.npmrc**

```
always-auth=true
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

**Note:** You don't need the `.npmrc` file when you use "public" access.

Answer (score 15):

First create the org: https://www.npmjs.com/org/create

Then run `npm publish --access public`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was that my **package name was scoped** i.e. it had a `supericium`, for exmaple: @supericium/package-name (or @pryansh/react-audio-gear).

But the catch here is, that you can use a `supericium` to prefix your package-name only if you have an organization's account on npmjs.com and as I didn't had it so a workaround was to remove `supericium`.

```js
// BEFORE
{
  "name": "@pryansh/react-audio-gear",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
```

```js
// AFTER 
{
  "name": "react-audio-gear",
  "version": "1.0.0",
```